# EXcel increment in formula

Tags: excel-formula, increment

I am working on excel sheet, but i am having challenge with incrementing; I want to move from a1-a2 to a3 etc. but it's moving from a1 to b1

shows the exact result i am looking for without manually doing it

[image]

A solution to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INDIRECT()` function:

`=FILTER(...,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDIRECT("'Participant info'!"&[reference-to-index]),...)`

where `[reference-to-index]` is an index you have running (for example in the cells below your formula) of the cell references just as plain text $A1, $A2, $A3, etc.

Comment: I would advise to use `INDEX('Participant info'!$A:$A,COLUMN(B:B))` instead of volatile INDIRECT